# Draw on click or touch event

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

im learnig javascript and try to develop a page to draw on. Change colors and linewidth are already in place. Now it is drawing, but just when I move the mouse. I'd like to add also on click on just on move. So I'm able to draw also points. I have put the drawCircle function in the function stopDraw, but this is not working as it should. Any ideas?

Second problem is that, I'd like to draw a circle without stroke. But as soon as I change the lineWidth, also my circle gets a stroke around. Please help...

```
// Setup event handlers

cb_canvas = document.getElementById("cbook");

cb_lastPoints = Array();

if (cb_canvas.getContext) {
    cb_ctx = cb_canvas.getContext('2d');
    cb_ctx.lineWidth = 14;
    cb_ctx.strokeStyle = "#0052f8";
    cb_ctx.lineJoin="round";
    cb_ctx.lineCap="round"
    cb_ctx.beginPath();

    cb_canvas.onmousedown = startDraw;
    cb_canvas.onmouseup = stopDraw;
    cb_canvas.ontouchstart = startDraw;
    cb_canvas.ontouchend = stopDraw;
    cb_canvas.ontouchmove = drawMouse;
}

function startDraw(e) {
if (e.touches) {
    // Touch event
    for (var i = 1; i <= e.touches.length; i++) {
        cb_lastPoints[i] = getCoords(e.touches[i - 1]); // Get info for finger #1
    }
}
else {
    // Mouse event
    cb_lastPoints[0] = getCoords(e);
    cb_canvas.onmousemove = drawMouse;
}

return false;
}

// Called whenever cursor position changes after drawing has started
function stopDraw(e) {
drawCircle(e);
e.preventDefault();
cb_canvas.onmousemove = null;
}

//Draw circle
function drawCircle(e) {
var canvasOffset = canvas.offset();
var canvasX = Math.floor(e.pageX-canvasOffset.left);
var canvasY = Math.floor(e.pageY-canvasOffset.top);
//var canvasPos = getCoords(e);

cb_ctx.beginPath();
cb_ctx.arc(canvasX, canvasY, cb_ctx.lineWidth/2, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
cb_ctx.fillStyle = cb_ctx.strokeStyle;
cb_ctx.fill();

}

function drawMouse(e) {
cb_ctx.beginPath();
if (e.touches) {
    // Touch Enabled
    for (var i = 1; i <= e.touches.length; i++) {
        var p = getCoords(e.touches[i - 1]); // Get info for finger i
    cb_lastPoints[i] = drawLine(cb_lastPoints[i].x, cb_lastPoints[i].y, p.x, p.y);
    }
}
else {
    // Not touch enabled
    var p = getCoords(e);
    cb_lastPoints[0] = drawLine(cb_lastPoints[0].x, cb_lastPoints[0].y, p.x, p.y);
}
cb_ctx.stroke();
cb_ctx.closePath();
//cb_ctx.beginPath();

return false;
}

// Draw a line on the canvas from (s)tart to (e)nd
function drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY) {
cb_ctx.moveTo(sX, sY);
cb_ctx.lineTo(eX, eY);
return { x: eX, y: eY };
}

// Get the coordinates for a mouse or touch event
function getCoords(e) {
if (e.offsetX) {
    return { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY };
}
else if (e.layerX) {
    return { x: e.layerX, y: e.layerY };
}
else {
    return { x: e.pageX - cb_canvas.offsetLeft, y: e.pageY - cb_canvas.offsetTop };
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your drawCircle function is wrapped in the canvas's onclick event. It should be

```
function drawCircle(e) {
    var canvasOffset = canvas.offset();
    var canvasX = Math.floor(e.pageX-canvasOffset.left);
    var canvasY = Math.floor(e.pageY-canvasOffset.top);
    cb_ctx.beginPath();
    cb_ctx.lineWidth = 0;
    cb_ctx.arc(canvasX,canvasY,cb_ctx.lineWidth/2,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    cb_ctx.fillStyle = cb_ctx.strokeStyle;
    cb_ctx.fill();
}
```

So you'll have to pass the event object from stop draw as well

```
function stopDraw(e) {
    drawCircle(e); //notice the change here
    e.preventDefault();
    cb_canvas.onmousemove = null;
}
```

Note that you're also setting you circle's radius to 0 which might be another reason why it's not showing up.

```
cb_ctx.lineWidth = 0;
cb_ctx.arc(canvasX,canvasY,cb_ctx.lineWidth/2,0,Math.PI*2,true);
```

0 divided by 2 is always zero. If you don't want to stroke around the circle just don't call stroke(). the drawCircle function isn't causing that, since there's a beginPath() call. I suspect it's because you don't beginPath() before calling stroke() in drawMouse.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I implemented all your suggestions, but it still does not work as it should. It works better though, but I get now this scenario:
- draw circle on click works
- as I start drawing a line, then the last circle drawn on the canvas gets a stroke around it

How can I fix this?

Comment: call beginPath() before you call drawLine(). You're not closing off the circle's path before you call stroke() when you draw a line.

Comment: its working. but now a funny thing happens. in the browser everything is OK, but on the mobile phone the circle is drawn in the top left corner of the screen.

Comment: is there a problem in the drawCircle function and with using pageX and pageY?

Comment: no, I'm guessing your problem is that here. drawLine(cb_lastPoints[i].x, cb_lastPoints[i].y... Change it to drawLine(cb_lastPoints[i-1].x, cb_lastPoints[i-1].y... to match up with the way you do your loops.

Comment: no it doesnt work. :((( did this, but it didn't work out. it stopped to draw the lines as it did before and again the circle was drawn in the top left screen.

Comment: don't know then. Something ending up in the top-left corner usually means that you're passing in a null or undefined value to one of your coordinates. Figure out what that is, and you'll be able to work backwards to find out what's causing the problem.

Comment: Can you tell me what to use to find that out? For instance to debug? Because phonegap doesn't tell anything useful

Comment: There's lots of different ways. Probably the easiest if you're just checking a couple values is to create a div somewhere and change set it's text to whatever values you're checking. Otherwise you can use an remote debugger like jsconsole.